# PHP with soap client API inetegration is not working

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, soap

I am new for handling soap API Request-Response, I need help to implement SMS code using SMS gateway API.
I am using PHP with curl request for send SMS through SMS Gateway API below is my code to send SMS to customer(s)

```
<?php
 define("USERNAME","#username#");
 define("PASSWORD","#password#");
 $soapUrl = "soap_wsdl_url"; 

 $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:templateSMS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="urn:ElbaridTNS" xmlns:ns3="namespace" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns3:AuthHeader>
          <username>USERNAME</username>
          <password>PASSWORD</password>
</ns3:AuthHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:templateSMS>
<Sms xsi:type="ns2:Sms"><phoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">phoneNumber</phoneNumber>
<message xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello User, this is test SMS message. We can successfully send SMS.</message>
<unicodeMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">test SMS</unicodeMessage>
<sms_type_id xsi:type="xsd:string">1</sms_type_id>
<notify xsi:type="xsd:string">0</notify>
<senderId xsi:type="xsd:string">SENDERID</senderId>
<priority xsi:type="xsd:string">2</priority>
<vbApp xsi:type="xsd:string">SoapRequest</vbApp>
<vbIdTime xsi:type="xsd:string">20161130101112</vbIdTime>
<destinationPort xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</destinationPort></Sms>
</ns1:templateSMS>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

   $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: templateSMS",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    );

    $url = $soapUrl;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;


    $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
    $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

    $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
    echo $parser['resultCode'];
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($parser);
    echo "</pre>";

   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I got this response on $parser['resultCode'] **"Send Unicast Message"**. I don't know what is the meaning of this response. I did R&Ds on this issue since 2 days but not getting any success.

Can anyone help me to fix the above issue?

Comment: Your code never checks if curl_exec returns false. And if it returns falls, you should also call a [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: Since that message is in the SOAP Response you receive from the API, the only ones being able to clarify what that means are the technical support from the respective SOAP API service.

Comment: I already contact to support team, they gave me a sample data that should be pass in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Support team gave me a request and response sample code that should pass in the xml format, below is the request, response sample structure

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:templateSMS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="urn:ElbaridTNS" xmlns:ns3="namespace" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns3:AuthHeader>
<username>username </username>
<password>password</password>
</ns3:AuthHeader>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:templateSMS>
<Sms xsi:type="ns2:Sms"><phoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxx</phoneNumber>
<message xsi:type="xsd:string">test SMS </message>
<unicodeMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">test SMS</unicodeMessage>
<sms_type_id xsi:type="xsd:string">1</sms_type_id>
<notify xsi:type="xsd:string">0</notify>
 <senderId xsi:type="xsd:string">SenderId</senderId>
 <priority xsi:type="xsd:string">2</priority>
 <vbApp xsi:type="xsd:string">SoapRequest</vbApp>
 <vbIdTime xsi:type="xsd:string">20161130101112</vbIdTime>
 <destinationPort xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</destinationPort></Sms>
 </ns1:templateSMS>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

**Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:templateSMS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:templateSMSResponse>
<templateSMSResponse xsi:type="xsd:string">0#!#200#!#http://198.101.210.203/Soap/service/elbarid|http://212.98.137.180/Soap/service/elbarid#!#SenderId 
</templateSMSResponse>
</ns1:templateSMSResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```